# cual es mas optimo para realizar una busqueda de un cliente por busqueda en un objeto o directamente una consulta

Tags: c#, sql-server

Este procedimiento me trae una lista de todos los clientes registrados y esto lo ejecuto en el Load 
y la variable TablaDatos lo tengo global para despues hacer la busqueda con el procedimiento "BusquedaPorCi"

```
 void TraerListadClientes()
          {

            try
            {
                var res = _Asistencia.VerificacionHuella();
                TablaDatos = res.Data;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
```

de esa manera busco los cliente pero nose si es la mejor manera ya que habria otra opcion donde yo envie
 el parametro gestor de base de datos para que me devuelva el resultado

```
          void BusquedaPorCi(string ci)  
        {              
            for (int i = 0; i < TablaDatos.Rows.Count; i++)  
             {  
                    if(TablaDatos.Rows[i]["CI"].ToString()== ci)  
                    {                         
                         Identificador = "Identificado";                            
                         MostarLabel(false);                         
                    }              
               }
            }
```

Se los agradeceria si me dan sus sugerencias .

Comment: Pienso que seria mejor que envíes el parámetro y la consulta te devuelva el dato en vez de traerte todo y empezar a buscar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende de tu ambiente.

La memoria es un recurso limitado y tener a todos los clientes en memoria puede consumir mucho espacio de la misma.

Por otro lado, el hacer la consulta por cliente permite liberar la memoria a cambio de consumir tráfico de red y posiblemente hacer lectura de disco en otro servidor (aunque puede estar en caché) porque espero que tengas la base de datos y la aplicación en distintos servidores.

En general, se acostumbra obtener los datos por cada cliente para liberar la memoria. Así se mantiene un balance de los recursos aunque termine por ser un poco menos eficiente. Es importante tener un buen índice que permita hacer la consulta de forma óptima para reducir lectura de disco.